# call php function from HTML string

Tags: php

I'm facing a problem to call PHP function from html code and fill arguments of function. 
After that the HTML code is output with returned values of functions.

for an example:

somewhere  In PHP file are defined functions

```
function html_field($type,$name,$value){ 
//some code here
return $out;
}
// or other example function
function boldme($text){
return "<b>$text</b>";
}
```

After that is generated html output in string with php functions inside (like tags)

HTML String:

`$html = "<h1><label for="foo">{call~html_field("text","name","value")} </label><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" /> </h1>"`

OR

`$html = "<h1><label for="foo">{call~boldme("text")} </label><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" /> </h1>"`

The solution should ends, like:

`$html = "<h1><label for="foo"><input type="text" name="name" ...> </label><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" /> </h1>"`

OR

`$html = "<h1><label for="foo"><b>text</b> </label><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" /> </h1>"`

It is required to filter this string...

NOTE:
The string containing the collected html data from  templates and themes,
they are unknowable files with **pure HTML inside**.

I was using `preg_replace_callback` to create needed functionality, but all gone now, thanks to my boss.... !@#!

Comment: It is unsafe, but you're looking for [eval()](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: I'd actually prefer `preg_replace_callback()` over `eval()` any day.

Comment: Im trying to skip eval()...

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you, but, simply calling `<?php echo myFunc($value); ?>` isn't enough?

Comment: Extending NemoStein solution $HTML = 'your html '. myFunc($value). 'more html '; should seems to solve your issue. Why you need callback or Eval for that matter.

Comment: sorry but no... 
because the string containing the html, templates and themes. they are unknowable, only the string containing collected html data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to parse a string and call some function based on it, you can use the `preg_replace_callback` function.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$html = "<p>{functionName('value1', 'value2')}</p>";

function contentParser($matches)
{   
    $function = $matches[1];
    $parameters = array_slice($matches, 2);

    return call_user_func_array($function, $parameters);
}

function functionName($valueA, $valueB)
{
    return "You called functionName with values " . $valueA . " and " . $valueB;
}

echo preg_replace_callback(
    "/\{(\w+)\([\"']([^\"']+)[\"'](?:, ?[\"']([^\"']+)[\"'])?\)\}/",
    "contentParser",
    $html);
```

This will print the following:

```
You called functionName with values value1 and value2
```

Note that my regex have a big problem.
You can enclose the values (in your html) in single or double quotes (" or '), and you CAN mix them...
This leads to a second problem, which you can't use either in your values (I don't check for escaped sequences).

A simpler patter that uses only one character as a value wrapper (and you can change that character, of course) is the following:

```
"/\{(\w+)\(#([^#]+)#(?:, ?#([^#]+)#)?\)\}/"
```

Here I'm using the sharp (#) as value delimiter, then, your html must look like this:

```
<p>{functionName(#value1#, #value2#)}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do the `$html` Strings come from? If it's static code, use standard php:

```
$html = '<h1><label for="foo">' . html_field("text","name","value") . '</label><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" /> </h1>';
```

If they are loaded from database or file or whatever, you have to options:

- make your own template engine, much work, few bugs, time wasted
- use a lightweight template engine like [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and define your functions as [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters)